# NSArray Removeallobject error in ios

Tags: iphone

i am having a array called temparray and have 2 seperate arrays .i have two buttons ,when i tap the first button it lodes the first array to the temp array,and when i tap the second button it lods the second array to the temparray.
my code is

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnlanselmlayalm:(id)sender
{
    [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:delegate.allSelectedVerseMalayalam];    
    [self.tab reloadData];
}
-(IBAction)_clickbtnlanselhindi:(id)sender
{
    [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:delegate.allSelectedVerseHindi];
    [self.tab reloadData];
}
```

allSelectedVerseMalayalam and allSelectedVerseHindi are two arrays which lodes from application delegate.after tap the first button it losds the first array and show it in tableview,but when i tap the scrond button i receve a warning in  `[tempArray removeAllObjects];` programe receiving signal sigrabat.and it crashes the app.then i put `[tempArray removeAllObjects];` again it crashes.
whats the problem in my code.please help me to find the eroor.
thanks in advance.

Comment: keep a breakpoint at [tempArray removeAllObjects]; and check if it is nil.

Comment: can't understand you because you don't know English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your `tempArray` is properly initialized and is in fact a `NSMutableArray` (`NSArray`s are immutable and don't support `addObject:`/`removeAllObjects`/etc)?

Comment: Hm. Try adding a `[tempArray count]` check before the `removeAllObjects` in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your tempArray object (retains & releases). Is tempArray a property ? How did you declared it ?

Answer (score 0):

did you initialize `tempArray` before you `removeAllObjects` method? check this is null or not.